# How, from silverlight 4, do I call a WCF on an https connection that requires client side certificates?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, https, client-side

In our application we have a silverlight app, sl.xap. It is hosted on https://xap.intra.net/getxapfile.html.

Once running in the browser, the sl.xap will make a call to a WCF service hosted on https://wcf.intra.net/wcf.svc.

Both xap.intra.net and wcf.intra.net expect client side certificates.

If I host the WCF Service on https://xap.intra.net/wcf.svc everything works great. Browser opens, asks for certificate, and away we go. Unfortunately, that is not an option for production because corporate policy blah blah blah.

So, I am frankly not sure where to go from here. I am still new at using SSL Client side certificates. I think I need to somehow, get and then pass the client certificate to the WCF. No idea how.

Any advice would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Give this a read - http://forums.silverlight.net/t/13275.aspx - it should set you off in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I finally got from the corporate IT Architechture guys was: you can't. Silverlight cannot access and send the client side certificates to a server over https.

This means, I have to download the XAP from the same connection that provides the web service. This allows Silverlight to make use of the existing SSL channel created by the browser.

Furthermore, if I needed to contact a 3rd party https client certificate expecting service, I would have to create a proxy service on my server to help out.